# C++ pointer to object's class member

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I have a class with an array inside. Inside of this array, I want to put a function pointer to a function which has the same-this pointer as my insance.

```
class Foo {
   std::vector <void (*baz)> bar;
   void baz () {};
}

Foo bundy;
bundy.bar.push_back (/*???*/);
```

How can this be done? I suppose, when I run it like `&Foo::baz()`, `baz` has no (valid) this pointer or doesn't point to the instance.

What could be good workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing a pointer to `*baz`, you could store an `std::function<void()>`.

Then you could store a lambda with a bound instance:

```
Foo bundy;
bundy.bar.push_back([&bundy](){ bundy.baz(); });
```

Your class would then look like this:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> bar;
    void baz() {};
};
```

Comment: what is a lambda? Thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: @Ceros Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Question: If I want to transpose the "function-pointer" into a variable, how do I do this?

Comment: Another question: how can I use the this-pointer instead of the class name? [&this] () {this.mamber();} doesn't seem to work